# How to configure basic FastCGI caching on nginx (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: php, ubuntu, caching, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to get basic FastCGI caching to work, but am running into trouble after following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-fastcgi-caching-with-nginx-on-your-vps).

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04, I ran the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nginx
apt-get install -y php-fpm
```

I then changed `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #   fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
    #   fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
    }
}
```

After adding a file called `time.php` in the server document root (`/var/www/html`) with the following contents:

`<?php echo time();`

and navigating `IP/time.php`, the file executes and displays a timestamp. On reloads, fresh timestamps are displayed.

If I uncomment the above lines, only a blank screen with `<html><body></body></html>` loads.

Why does adding:

```
        fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
```

result in a blank html page?  How can this be fixed to cache `time.php` and serve the cached version to future requests?

Note:  I did see that `/etc/nginx/cache` was created and does contain data. I changed the directory to `777` permissions to eliminate permission issues.

Comment: have you tried restarting nginx? /etc/init.d/nginx restart

Comment: Yes, and ive tried many different configs (restarting each time), but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/nginxfastcgi
$ chown www-data: /var/cache/nginxfastcgi
```

THEN IN YOUR CONFIG

```
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginxfastcgi levels=1:2 keys_zone=fastcgicache:10m inactive=10m max_size=64m;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$request_method$host$request_uri;

    fastcgi_cache_lock on;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 5m;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

server {
    listen 80;

    root **************;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name *************;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            fastcgi_cache fastcgicache;
    }
}
```